# Insert carriage return in a vimscript variable

Tags: vimscript, substitute, line-breaks

A vimscript variable `longstring` (for instance obtained by `let longstring = getline('.')`) contains a long sequence of characters (numbers, letters, commas, spaces, ...).

I want to replace a specific character, let it be `A`, with a carriage return, so that when I use `call writefile(longstring, 'this.file', '')` I obtain a file with several lines, each containing what was found between two consecutive `A`s.

I tried with `let longstring = substitute(longstring,'A','\r','g')`, which only results (after `writefile`) in a single long line file with `^M` in place of `A`. I guess I'm using the wrong replace string, but `\n` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `writefile` must be a list and each list item 
represents a line in the new file.

Using [`split()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#split%28%29) you could make a pattern-separated list out of
`longstring` as follows:

```
call writefile(split(longstring, "A"), 'this.file', '')
```

and obtain the intended result.